# How to alter elements in a for loop depending on numbers in an array?

Tags: php

How would I alter certain elements in the inner for loop if I am using an array with numbers?

e.g

```
$decryptFields[0] = '1';
$decryptFields[1] = '3';

if($z) == ANY OF THOSE NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY DO SOMETHING.

$x[$i][$z]
```

so if the inner for loop contains any of those numerals then something will happen e.g maybe I'll make the text bold.

```
foreach($decryptFields as $dfield) {
    echo $dfield;
}
for($i = 0; $i< 10; $i++) {
    for($z = 0; $z < $columnLength; $z++) {
        echo $x[$i][$z];
    }
}       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I will do my best to answer it.

If you want to 'do something' if the value $z equals any of the values in the array $decryptFields, you can simply use:

```
if(in_array($z, $decryptFields)){ /*do something*/}
```

EDIT: It seems $z is also an array of values.

In that case, use :

```
$intersection = array_intersect($z, $decryptFields);
foreach($intersection as $key=>$value){
    echo "<b>$value</b>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  // Build a string
  $str = '';
  for ($z = 0; $z < $columnLength; $z++) {
    $str .= $x[$i][$z];
  }
  // If any of the elements of $decryptFields are present in the string, wrap
  // it in <span class='bold'></span>
  foreach ($decryptFields as $dfield) {
    if (strpos($str, $dfield) !== FALSE) {
      $str = "<span class='bold'>$str</span>";
      break;
    }
  }
  // Echo the result
  echo $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check multiple items for match to any item of some array, best solution is to build index for the array:

```
foreach ($decryptFields as $key => $value) $decryptIndex[$value] = $key;
```

And use that index later:

```
if (isset($decryptIndex[$x[$i][$z]])) {
    // Do something
}
```

And if you need to get index of matching element in $decryptFields array, use $decryptIndex[$x[$i][$z]]

This is the fastest method, since associative array implementation in PHP is very fast.